# How to convert a nested for of loop into a custom iterator?

Tags: javascript, performance, iterator, yield

I have the following code:

```
function* getPossibleCollidersWith(shape) {
  for (let square of retrieve(shape)) {
    for (let neighbor of square) {
      yield neighbor;
    }
  }
}
```

This works, but uses generators and yield, which is very slow. I've benchmarked it using Chrome's profiler and it is *significantly* less performant than removing the generator and just iterating through the nested loop in the client code.

However, it's a lot of boilerplate to do a nested loop every time I want to get a shape's neighbors. I would like to create a custom iterator to see if that has better performance than the generator function, but all the examples I see are rather complex and involve keeping track of indicies, null values, etc.

Is there a simple way to convert the above code into a custom iterator? Ideally I'd like to keep using `for of` loops to return each element, but all the examples I see online involve error-prone index-tracking.

I would like the client code to look like this, if possible:

```
for (let neighbor of getPossibleCollidersWith(shape)) {
  // handle neighbor
}
```

Comment: how are you using that function do you just do `[...getPossibleColidersWith()]`?

Comment: @miyavmiyav I've included some example client code of how I'd like to call the function / iterator at the bottom of the question

Comment: I don't exatly get your question but are you looking for something like this?
`const getPossibleCollidersWithShape = (shape) => {
  let array = [];
  for (let square of retrieve(shape)) {
    array = [...array, square];
  }
  return array;
}`

Comment: @miyavmiyav No, that involves a ton of allocation. I'm developing a Javascript game and this code runs in a tight loop (collision checking) so that sort of thing would likely be just as bad as the generator in terms of performance.

Comment: IF you said iterating over them is faster why not just pass a function as parameter?

Comment: `const getPossibleCollidersWithShape = (shape, fn) => {
  for (let square of retrieve(shape)) {
    for (let neighbor of square) {
      fn(neighbor);
    }
  }
}

`

Comment: That way you dont have that boiler plate code but you are doing iteration each time

Comment: @miyavmiyav That's a pretty good solution actually. If no one comes along with an iterator approach then I might just do that. The only unfortunate issue I see with using a callback like you describe though is that if I want to reference variables outside the loop body I'll have to create a closure, which would have to be re-evaluated every frame. I've checked though, and the performance of this is significantly better than the generator function. The only con is that it seems to cause a lot of GC churn.

Comment: Why you don't use just a `.map`? `getPossibleCollidersWith = (shape) => retrieve(shape).flatMap(square => square.map(neighbor => neighbor))`

Comment: @A1exandrBelan That's also a lot of allocation (flat map and then mapping is recreating the array twice, as opposed to iterators which simply iterate through the elements without re-allocating a giant array twice). Performance is very important here (which is why I'm looking for something better than the generator function, which has perfect ergonomics, but poor performance)